# creating subdomain in VPS (Hostinger) under my domain example.com

Tags: cloud, vps

I am new to hostinger VPS.
I will be highly grateful if any one guide me how to setup my subdomain in my hosting step by step.
I could able to setup my domain with my VPS but unable to setting up the subdomain.

Comment: Are you using any control panel for your VPS or have you setup it up manually?